# Infinite While loop flowchart

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

```
while (True):
    a=int(input()) #input
    if(a<0):
        break
```

I wanted to create a program that loop until the user enters some value then the loop would break. Therefore I'm trying this way.I have to draw the flow chart too.

how to draw {while(True):} situation?

What will be the flowchart for this infinite while loop code?

Comment: Arrow leading back to the 1st step?

Comment: Yes, only want to know how while(True) draw in flowchart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `input()` function in Python is a blocking function. This means that the program will not terminate until the `input()` call returns, and this in turn won't return until the user provides an input. And this should be reflected in the flowchart.

The flowchart would look something like this:

[image: flowchart]